# Matlab: Conditional sum

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate a conditional sum of a vector.

Ex:

A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
Condtional: a > 4
Result = 5 + 6 = 11

How can I do this in Matlab?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
result = sum(A(A>4));
assert(result==11);
```